# Index out of range Vs code python cartpole game

Tags: python

I am running cartpole game in Vs code in python with following code -

```
import gym

env = gym.make('CartPole-v1') #create the environment

def basic_policy(obs): # determines what action to take
    angle = obs[2]        #observing the pole angle in env
    return 0 if angle < 0 else 1

totals = [] # list of the total reward accumulated for each episode(or run)

for episode in range(10):
    episode_rewards = 0 #the rewards for the episode 
    obs = env.reset() # initial observation and everytime i start again it resets
    action = 1 # move cart to left or right (or by 1 bit)
    for step in range (1000): # 1000 total steps
        action = basic_policy(obs) # perform action based on obs
        env.render() # accumulate reward after action
        obs,reward,done,info = env.step(action) #gives the following details after the action
        episode_rewards += reward #add reward at the current time
        if done :
            totals.append(episode_rewards)
            break

print(totals)

print('The longest number of timesteps the pole was balanced : ' + str(max(totals)))
```

Error is -

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\Users\Admin\1BM22AD022\AI\file1.py", line 16, in 
> action = basic_policy(obs) # perform action based on obs
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "c:\Users\Admin\1BM22AD022\AI\file1.py", line 6, in basic_policy
> angle = obs[2]        #observing the pole angle in env
> ~~~^^^
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Whereas when i running it in google collab answer is coming like this -

[26.0, 60.0, 51.0, 40.0, 40.0, 24.0, 36.0, 41.0, 45.0, 49.0]
The longest number of timesteps the pole was balanced : 60.0

So what's wrong can anyone please point out

Comment: The tuple *obs* has fewer than 3 elements

Comment: don't spam with irrelevant tags

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Gym documentation](https://arc.net/l/quote/xevjefbl), the `env.reset()` returns 2 outputs: `observation` and `info`. You need unpack these 2 returned values but you are assigning the tuple to `obs` variable instead.

Instead of

```py
obs = env.reset()  # here obs is a tuple(observations, info)
```

Use

```py
obs, info = env.reset()
```